# iOS How to implement a countdown screen before the user sees the view

Tags: ios, view, controller, navigation

I was wondering what is the best way to implement a countdown screen before showing the user the game view. For a more detailed example, I want the user to see a screen that displays 3...2...1...GO ! and than the game will appear.

Currently in my application I am using a navigation controller as my main menu where you can select multiple games to choose from. When a user selects one of the game buttons this is where I want the countdown screen to appear before my game interfaces does.

Solutions that I have thought about:
1) should I implement a new view controller that i push on the navigation controller to perform the count down ( seems like a waste)
2) is there  a way to blank everything on a view and show a countdown first?

Thanks in advance for your help and cooperation !

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way i think is as soon as user selects a game, add your 3..2..1. Go screen on the same view..as soon as u present this u can also start preparing to create your game interface(but do not present). After GO appears, remove this countdown view and present your game..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the effect you are after. If you push a view controller onto the navigation stack, you'll need to use a pop transition.

My suggestion would be to open the game view controller and put a full-screen sized overlay view on top of it with your countdown message. Have the game VC manage the countdown view. When the countdown is complete, you could fade it, shrink it to a point, do some sort of clock wipe or keyhole animation, or whatever you want, easily and simply. (Some things are obviously easier than others. Cross-fades, shrinks and the like are trivial. clock wipes and keyhole transitions are much harder and require pretty advanced Core Animation skills.

Comment: Hi, sorry I searched "full screen sized overlay view " and nothing came up. Whats the best way about implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

What platform will this be for? For a full screen overlay I would try UIPopoverViewController if on an iPad. Otherwise, try a view controller presented modally. I believe you can set the transparency of either type to less than 1 so the underlying view shows through. In this case it would be nice to display the selected game's opening screen during the countdown. Of course it would be dark because of the overlying view. But it would provide a glimpse into what is to come.